# Comparing unicode characters in Junit

Tags: java, unicode, junit

I had problems in some flow with unicode chars in some of my flows. So i fixed the flow and added a test.

```
assertEquals("Björk", buyingOption.getArtist());
```

the buyingOption.getArtist() will return the same name that is on ,here is a snippet :

[image]

but junit will fail with the message :

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: null 
Expected :Bj?rk
Actual   :Bj?rk
    at com.delver.update.system.AECSystemTest.basicOperationtsTest1(AECSystemTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to the default encoding used for your Java source files. The `ö` in the string literal in the JUnit source code is probably being converted to something else when the test is compiled.

To avoid this, use Unicode escapes (`\uxxxx`) in the string literals in your JUnit source code:

```
assertEquals("Bj\u00F6rk", buyingOption.getArtist());
```

Comment: This is just a workaround and makes the string unreadable (what if you have to test Chinese?), I think the best answer is AlexR one, and I would add that UTF-8 should be default and standard everywhere. It should be taught just after ASCII, then should be taught that ASCII is obsolete, and same for other non-unicode encodings (as windows-1252 and similar ones).

Comment: PS. UTF-8 is space-saving (it enlarges itself according to the printed char) and allows all languages of the world, as it's a (smart) representation of Unicode.

Comment: The code should be human readable, and "Bj\u00F6rk" is not.
How the source code is stored: "binary", that can allow everything. It's not a problem of humans the representation, else we should see 01010101 and calculate the meaning. The solution is here since 1991 (Unicode) and since about 20 years is in every computer (at lower layer). Later, the idea of UTF-8 for space saving made obsolete the others. This user wants to test that "Björk" is the string, so the standard should be, that all the projects that break unicode are breaking a best-practice. Filosophy but... in 2020...

Comment: I just meant this: every platform should use UTF-8 (since at long time).
If a platform uses another encoding, there is a problem (a best-practice is broken). The problem is that platform not using a W3C standard.
UTF8 is the future that will never became present if people don't know that all the technical problems have been solved, and it works always. Just we need to massively adopt them.
Example: what if a test fails and the tester doesn't see that "Bj\u00F8rk" is not passing, because not equal to "Bj\u00F6rk". Time waste because of lack of readability. Take care.

Comment: In my team we do like that. If a new worker joins the team, runs a build and a test with unicode will fail, he will have fix his IntelliJ or Eclipse (a comment: // if this test fails, do this and this). Advantage: we SEE the strings in our code. We live with what we have, i remember the times when i had to send a letter to China and i had to require the receiver to send me her address in a Word document. Now we have no problems by reading Chinese in email body.
Notepad++ has UTF8 as default (I was 1 of the requesters of this improvement of NP++). 
World changes fast, IT faster, let's fight

Comment: Well, good for you. I also use UTF-8 as the default myself. But the point is: The OP had a problem that was likely related to the platforms' default character encoding. In my answer I explain why the problem happens and how to solve it in a way that does not depend on the platform and which is actually the official, documented way to do it in Java. If you think that an answer saying "change your platform and setup a policy for your whole team to do the same" would have been better, then well, you are welcome to post it :)

Comment: Ok, we both explained, regards.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Grodriguez but would like to suggest you to change your default encoding to UTF-8 and forget about this kind of problems.

How to do this? It depends on your IDE. For example in Eclipse go to Window/Preferences then type "encoding", choose Workspace and change encoding to UTf-8

Comment: Ok, I guess then there is some configuration for maven junit , or the compiler plugin.

Comment: @Roman - in your Maven pom.xml, you need to specify the encoding of your source files to match your editor. This will ensure consistent compilation in any environment. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/POM+Element+for+Source+File+Encoding

Comment: McDowell: Changing your default encoding is fine as long as you work alone, or at least in a "controlled" environment. However things get more difficult if you are part of a team, as everyone might be working on a different environment. Using Unicode escapes in your source files is fool-proof -- file encodings do not matter any more, regardless of what editor / compiler / setup you use.

Comment: This is one of those fundamental Java design flaws: there is no place to specify the (ASCII-compatible) encoding in the source file itself. It is insane that we are expected to stick to 7 bits when the language has 16 bit chars, plus a nasty hack for the rest of them.

Comment: This worked for me in Android Studio. I changed the project encodings to UTF-8 and it worked.

Comment: @tchrist "a nasty hack for the rest of them" - yeah, I'm not fond of UTF-16 either. Then again, UTF-32 would be the same. I think the only ideal structure is for them not to have exposed the char storage in the first place.

Comment: @Trejkaz I agree that exposing the physical layout was an error. Notice how "newer" languages  (or at least newer approaches) provide instead an abstract logical character without exposing internals.

Comment: UTF-8 should be default and standard everywhere. It should be taught just after ASCII, then should be taught that ASCII is obsolete, and same for other non-unicode encodings (as windows-1252 and similar ones).

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution was to change the default encoding before running mvn test

My fix to this issue was to set the ENV var JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS before running

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"    
mvn test
```