# How do I get other language in feature file parsed?

Tags: java, selenium, internationalization, cucumber, gherkin

When I send the following in my feature file,
It returns assertError parsing the french language.

Example feature file :
Then I verify error message "Une valeur est exigée." is shown

Getting :
 Then I verify error message "Une valeur est exig?e." is shown                                            # SolutionWebSteps.verifyErrorMessage(String)
      java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Une valeur est exig?e.] but found [Une valeur est exigée.]

Please note that I dont want to change #language: fr
I wanted to assert the some values from other language

Comment: Maybe this hepls - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918661/junit-fails-on-french-string-assertion

Comment: please share your code