# What is Comparison Failure, null expected in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

I am trying compare two strings using assertEquals(s1,s2);
I am getting Comparison error<> null expected in it.
Help me out in this.?

Comment: Use the debugger to ensure that both Strings are non-null.  Or print out the values before you test them.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using unicode characters like in  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237581/comparing-unicode-characters-in-junit)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(You don't say what version of JUnit you are using, and it could matter ... though probably not.)

It means that the unit test has an expression that evaluates to `null` as the `expected` argument of an `assertEquals`, and the `actual` argument does not evaluate to `null`.

It is not possible to say what this really means without looking at your code, but it could either be a bug in the unit test (e.g. the arguments around the wrong way) or a bug in the code under test ... or both.  As to *why* you are getting a `null`, that depends on the unit tests and/or the code it is testing.  You'll need to do your own investigation by looking at the source code, using a debugger, etcetera.

Note that the `assertEquals` method (see below) compares objects using `equals` (not `==`) and takes care to avoid throwing an NPE it either or both arguments are `null`.  So the people who are suggesting that you test for `null` first are missing the point.

Here's the Junit 4.4 code:

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null && actual == null)
        return;
    if (expected != null && isEquals(expected, actual))
        return;
    else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
        String cleanMessage= message == null ? "" : message;
        throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String)expected, 
                                    (String)actual);
    }
    else
        failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
    }
}

private static boolean isEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    return expected.equals(actual);
}
```

As you can see, the `null` cases are dealt with ...

Answer (score 0):

JUnit calls the .equals() method to determine equality in the method assertEquals(Object o1, Object o2). So, you are definitely safe using assertEquals(string1, string2). (Because Strings are Objects) provided both the objects are non-null. Another way of evaluating it is using assertTrue:

```
assertTrue(s1.equals(s2));
```

Comment: It is actually recommended to use assertEquals instead of assertTrue to check the equality of two objects as the message when the assertion fails is more easier to interpret.

Comment: This statement is questionable too:  *"assertEquals checks the equality of the objects. It is not a good idea to compare string with equality"*.  In fact, `assertEquals` uses `Object.equals` ... and that is **the correct way** to compare Strings.  (It does NOT use `==` ... read the code, and the javadocs.).  And if you are actually talking about the correct way to use `assertTrue`: 1) that is not obvious, 2) `assertTrue` is a red herring, 'cos he's not using it, and 3) that's a bad idea anyway; see Pangea's comment.