# Java string to byte array, loosing spcial cahracter §

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding

I have to convert a string that has "§" character to byte array and back to string.
I noticed all the "§"s got replaced by "?"s.

```
I tried it with encoding:
new String(message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"))
new String(message.getBytes("UTF8"))
new String(message.getBytes("UTF16"))
```

and not getting the same string back.

Edited:

Found out the issue occurs in UTs runtime.
Solved by either running with:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
```

or adding

```
<configuration>
   <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
</configuration>
```

to the surefire plugin

Comment: `new String(message.getBytes("UTF8"))` works at least on Java 14.

Comment: Made some progress.. On a brand new hello world project works fine. (with java 8)
Yet still fails on a JUnit unit test

Comment: Ok found it!

Sould use:
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"  before mvn test. thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237581/comparing-unicode-characters-in-junit

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same encoding when converting to bytes and when converting back to string. Any of the encodings you've tried should work. For example:

```
new String(message.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-1")
```

It would be better (runs faster, fewer possibilities for errors) to specify the encoding as a Charset object instead of as a string. For example in this case you could use `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1`.

Comment: this also works. but in my situation the code is more complicated than new String(message.getBytes("UTF8")) and is not mine to alter. I could recreate the issue using new String(message.getBytes("UTF8")) but needed a less intrusive solution.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your code depends on the platform default encoding and will break when you move it to a new platform. It's never a good idea to use the `String(byte[])` constructor.

Comment: Agree, but this time it's not my code, only responsible for the input and output. It actually works fine on production, but fails tests

Comment: Test failures reveal that there's a real problem in the code. It's a lucky coincidence that your current production environment isn't broken, but relying on luck is not a good long term strategy.